# Issue with static functions, g++ says the class hasn't been declared

Tags: c++, g++, static-methods

I am trying to compile this code, and g++ keeps telling me that 'TimeFinder' has not been declared

Header File

```
#ifndef _TIMEFINDER_H
#define _TIMEFINDER_H
#include <vector>
#include "timefinder.cpp"
using namespace std;
class TimeFinder
{
public:
    static vector<int> time_from_name(string filename);
    static int calc_seconds (vector <int> time);

};
#endif
```

CPP File

```
#include "timefinder.h"
using namespace std;
vector<int> TimeFinder::time_from_name(string filename)//Line 14
{
    //Method Body
}

int TimeFinder::calc_seconds (vector <int> time1)//Line 37
{

    //Method Body
}
```

Why is this going on?  I looked at other examples online, and my code seems to match what works for other people...

Edit: The exact error messages are

timefinder.cpp:14: error: ‘TimeFinder’ has not been declared

timefinder.cpp:37: error: ‘TimeFinder’ has not been declared

Edit2: I'm sorry I'm not very good at this yet, but I would like to thank everyone for their suggestions.  Hopefully my code quality will begin to improve because of them.

Comment: Are you pathing timefinder.cpp in the right way? I mean, if it's in the same place you have the rest of the code.

Comment: Yeah, it's all in the same directory

Comment: Can you add the exact error message from GCC? Also, `using namespace <whatever>` in a header file is extremely bad practise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not do this:

```
#include "timefinder.cpp"
```

You are pulling your definitions into your header so they appear before their declarations.

There is a lot of other stuff wrong with your code - the use of static members in the first place, passing vectors and strings by value when they should be references, and placing using directives in header files, but removing that #include should fix the immediate problem.

Comment: Why not?  Is that a thing just for classes with static methods?

Comment: No, its a very basic thing for all C++ source files.

Comment: All of my other files have the header include the cpp file, and they are all working fine.  What can go wrong from including the cpp file?

Comment: @Nawaz I'm getting a bit tired of comments like that from you. If it's not correct, say what would be correct, preferably in an answer of your own.

Comment: @mrswmmr I've given you correct advice, and explained the problem. The rest is up to you.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use static members?  Don't I need to create an object of this class when I implement these methods if I don't?

Comment: What can go wrong, @Mrswmmr? Well, for starters, the problem described *in this question* can occur. Also, you risk breaking the *one-definition rule* if any of your headers gets included by more than one source file. Also, you nullify any reduction in compile time you might have seen from using *separate compilation* because all your code will get compiled every time you change anything.

Comment: @mrswmmr It seems to me that what you're trying to achieve here would be rather implemented with functions. Static members are sort of "global" to a class, so methods acting on them must be called in a correct order.

Comment: Okay.  I changed the things that were causing errors or were bad form.  My only remaining question is if there is a way to call methods (that are no longer static) without creating an object to call them on

Comment: @mrswmmr If they are not static, and you don't want to call them on a class instance, make them ordinary functions, not class members.

Answer (score 0):

#include "timefinder.cpp"

Header files usually don't include their .cpp implementation file but only whatever other .h file is required to satisfy the definitions required. Usually it's the other way around where .cpp files include the required .h files necessary to fulfill the dependencies.

using namespace std;

This can also cause a lot of havoc and should be avoided in header files. In header files you should always fully qualify your names with their namespace. The reason is if you import this header file into another one that defines the same symbol locally in their namespace like "cout" then both the std::cout and user::cout would clash and cause a compile error or even worse possibly pick the wrong definition and cause a linking error later.